# How do I evaluate value which potentially is not supplied?

Tags: kql

I'm trying to make Azure monitor workbook with Azure Resource Graph (ARG) query as backend. There is dropdown presented to use to choose datetime value which is passed as parameter to ARG to filter results. It's expressed as `{dateCreated:start}` value in query. This works fine as long as there is something selected by user in dropdown, problem is that if nothing is selected in datetime field then condition essentially becomes `coalesce(todatetime(),todatetime('2016-11-09T02:53:17.4582226Z'))` which obviously fails validation logic since todatetime() expects something being passed to it. Is there something in KQL which will allow to overcome this?

```
 Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| where tags['datecreated'] >  coalesce(todatetime({dateCreated:start}),todatetime('2016-11-09T02:53:17.4582226Z') )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iff()` and `isempty()` will do the trick for you:

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| where tags['datecreated'] > iff(isempty({dateCreated:start}), todatetime('2016-11-09T02:53:17.4582226Z'), todatetime({dateCreated:start}))
```